# Trac Error. Missing or invalid form token. Do you have cookies enabled?

Tags: ajax, post, cookies, trac

I'm developing a plugin for Trac and trying to submit some info to the database

The scheme is:

1. Check a user you want to add to a department
2. Click a button to issue an ajax POST request
3. Process Request.

Everything was pretty fine while I was working with old 0.11 release. (not sure if that's the reason.

The company I've been working at updated Trac to the current stable 1.0.1 release and something is really wrong now.

Sending POST request without any data like this:

`$.post("trac_dep_policy");`

Went fine, but if I try to add some data:

`$.post("trac_dep_policy",  { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );`

I get 400 Bad Request error. 
After some  debugging I figured out it's the protection against CSRF attacks that is working against me. (web/main.py)

The question is simple - how should I deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF protection is [auto-added to each form](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/4049) by a combination of in-place Genshi template modification and read-back on POST request, and I know this has been added very early, fixed version in Trac 0.10.2 release to be clear.

You'll need to use XMLRPC protocol (see [XMLRPC plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin)) or read the hidden form token yourself.

Comment: XMLRPC seems like overdoing things a bit, plus XMLRPC plugin has some problems with account manager and digest auth, which I'd like to avoid. As for the second one - any example maybe? Reading the token may not be a problem, but I'm not sure how to pass down to the python backend.

Comment: Care to share some hints? It might be "easy", but other users coming after you might get help here by reading your solution. You are able and even encouraged to post and accept your own answer for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple enough:

Just as @hasienda mentioned in his answer - each form in Trac is provided with a hidden input inside a `div` element with a certain `name` tag and a token `value`:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="__FORM_TOKEN" value="9c69c37f52f669fb99b095e4">
    </div> 
</form>
```

Now, everything you'll need to do a successful POST request via ajax is to pass this `__FORM_TOKEN` value together with your data:

```
var token_value = $("input[name=__FORM_TOKEN]").val();
$.post(url, {__FORM_TOKEN: token_value, data: your_data})
```